# Other sidechains on the Stellar network besides ZkVM?

Tags: network, protocol

*Premise: I'm still in the learning process of anything that is blockchain and Stellar*

I've recently discovered ZkVM (here a nice article: https://medium.com/stellar-developers-blog/zkvm-a-new-design-for-fast-confidential-smart-contracts-d1122890d9ae) and I'm understanding that this is a protocol that can be used to become a sidechain of any blockchain. Quote from the technical white paper:

> A ZkVM blockchain can work with any consensus protocol, from
>   proof-of-work to Federated Byzantine Consensus.

source: https://github.com/stellar/slingshot/blob/main/zkvm/docs/zkvm-design.md

The team behind ZkVM worked for or in collaboration with Interstellar, so it is heavily promoted for (and I guess built for) Stellar. And I'm understanding that the specific implementation for Stellar of ZkVM is Slingshot, again a project by Interstellar.

Since I've discovered ZkVM, I've been wondering whether there are other Stellar sidechain projects. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 2):

Responded on Reddit but will respond here as well.

OrbitLens is also working on a sidechain called [Project Centaurus.](https://galactictalk.org/d/2168-centaurus-second-layer-payment-network-exchange-and-scaling-solution)

> Project Centaurus is the second layer payment network, exchange, and scaling solution for Stellar. It's a platform with very high throughput that allows a few independent organizations to create a protected decentralized segment on Stellar Network with a multisig vault account. Users can instantly transfer/trade tokens inside the cluster with zero fees.